# Python How to end an infinite loop after 3 tries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following loop which is an infinite loop. It loops as long as the request code is not equal =`200` and each time it tries sending an email.

I need to end the loop after 3 tries, then send the email once and exit the loop.

Any advise?

```
while True:
    r = requests.get("http://www.website.com/test11")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        break
    else:
        sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,subject, message,login, password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an email no matter what, you can use this:

```
count=0
while count < 3:
    r = requests.get("http://www.website.com/test11")
    if r.status_code == 200 
        break
    count+=1

sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,subject, message,login, password)
```

If you want to send the email only in case of failiure, use this:

```
count=0
success = False
while count < 3:
    r = requests.get("http://www.website.com/test11")
    if r.status_code == 200 
        success = True
        break
    count+=1

if(not success)
    sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,subject, message,login, password)
```

Comment: can we add sleep timer between each request ?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a slightly obscure `else:` clause on loops that is handy here - it runs if and only if the loop ended by running to completion (ie, it is skipped if you hit a `break`). It looks like this:

```
for _ in range(3):
    r = requests.get("http://www.website.com/test11")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        break

else:
    sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,subject, message,login, password)
```